# Deferencing hash of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, nested, dereference

Sorry for this long post, the code should be easy to understand for veterans of Perl. I'm new to Perl and I'm trying to figure out this bit of code:

```
my %regression;

print "Reading regression dir: $opt_dir\n";

foreach my $f ( glob("$opt_dir/*.regress") ) {
    my $name = ( fileparse( $f, '\.regress' ) )[0];
    $regression{$name}{file} = $f;

    say "file $regression{$name}{file}";
    say "regression name $regression{$name}";
    say "regression name ${regression}{$name}";

    &read_regress_file( $f, $regression{$name} );
}


sub read_regress_file {
    say "args @_";

    my $file = shift;
    my $href = shift;

    say "href $href";

    open FILE, $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";

    while ( <FILE> ) {
        next if /^\s*\#/ or /^\s*$/;
        chomp;

        my @tokens = split "=";
        my $key    = shift @tokens;
        $$href{$key} = join( "=", @tokens );
    }

    close FILE;
}
```

The `say` lines are things I added to debug.

---

My confusion is the last part of the subroutine `read_regress_file`. It looks like `href` is a reference from the line `my $href = shift;`. However, I'm trying to figure out how the hash that was passed got referenced in the first place.

`%regression` is a hash with keys of `$name`. The `.regress` files the code reads are simple files contains variables and their values in the form of:

```
var1=value
var2=value
...
```

So it looks like the line

```
my $name = (fileparse($f,'\.regress'))[0];
```

is creating the keys as scalars and the line

```
$regression{$name}{file} = $f;
```

actually makes `$name` into a hash.

In my debugging lines

```
say "regression name $regression{$name}";
```

prints the reference, for instance

```
regression name HASH(0x7cd198)
```

but

```
say "regression name ${regression}{$name}";
```

prints a name, like

```
regression name {filename}
```

with the file name inside the braces.

However, using

```
say "regression name $$regression{$name}";
```

prints nothing.

From my understanding, it looks like `regression` is an actual hash, but the references are the nested hashes, `name`.

Why does my deference test line using braces work, but the other form of dereferencing (`$$`) not work?

Also, why is the name still surrounded by braces when it prints? Shouldn't I be dereferencing `$name` instead?

I'm sorry if this is difficult to read. I'm confused which hash is actually referenced, and how to deference them if the reference is the nested hash.

Comment: When in doubt about your structures, [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is of _great_ help.
Try `use Data::Dumper;` and then (in `read_regress_file`) `print Data::Dumper->Dump([$href]);`. You must pass a reference, i.e. either `$href` or `\%regression`.

Comment: Your question is very much lacking focus. You talk a lot about your confusion but never ask a question. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tough one. You've found some very awkward code that displays what may well be a bug in Perl, and you're getting confused over dereferencing Perl data structures. Standard Perl installations include the full set of documentation, and I suggest you take a look at `perldoc perlreftut` which is also available online at [perldoc.com](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

The most obvious thing is that you are writing very old-fashioned Perl. Using an ampersand `&` to call a Perl subroutine hasn't been considered good practice since v5.8 was released fourteen years ago

I don't think there's much need to go beyond your clearly experimentatal lines at the start of the first `for` loop. Once you have understood this the rest should follow

```
say "file $regression{$name}{file}";
say "regression name $regression{$name}";
say "regression name ${regression}{$name}";
```

First of all, expanding data structure references within a string is unreliable. Perl tries to do what you mean, but it's very easy to write something ambiguous without realising it. It is often much better to use `printf` so that you can specify the embedded value separately. For instance

```
printf "file %s\n", $regression{$name}{file};
```

That said, you have a problem. `$regression{$name}` accesses the element of hash `%regression` whose key is equal to `$name`. That value is a reference to another hash, so the line

```
say "regression name $regression{$name}";
```

prints something like

```
regression name HASH(0x29348b0)
```

which you really don't want to see

Your first try `$regression{$name}{file}` accesses the element of the secondary hash that has the key `file`. That works fine

But `${regression}{$name}` should be the same as `$regression{$name}`. Outside a string it is, but inside it's like `${regression}` and `{$name}` are treated separately

There are really too many issues here for me to start guessing where you're stuck, especially without being able to talk about specifics. But it may help if I rewrite the initial code like this

```
my %regression;
print "Reading regression dir: $opt_dir\n";

foreach my $f ( glob("$opt_dir/*.pl") ) {

    my ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($f, '\.regress');

    $regression{$name}{file} = $f;
    my $file_details = $regression{$name};

    say "file $file_details->{file}";

    read_regress_file($f, $file_details);
}
```

I've copied the hash reference to `$file_details` and passed it to the subroutine like that. Can you see that each element of `%regression` is keyed by the name of the file, and that each value is a *reference to* another hash that contains the values filled in by `read_regress_file`?

I hope this helps. This isn't really a forum for teaching language basics so I don't think I can do much better

Comment: Borodin, thanks for the extensive reply. I should have stated I'm not much of a programmer and neither are my colleagues. I know TCL, and this code was written last week :)

I'm a little more clear on this. The value of a hash key must be a scalar, so a nested hash is always reported as a reference to the nested hash. This, combined with the awkward syntax to call them (and also how they behave when passed to subs, was confusing, especially since there are 3 ways to dereference stuff.

`printf` is also useful; I'll be sure to use that when debugging instead.

Cheers!

Comment: @jktstance: It would help you to be clearer with your nomenclature. Hashes and arrays have *elements*. Each element has a *key* (or an *index*) and a scalar *value*. Hashes are indexed by strings, while arrays are indexed by non-negative integers. I'm not sure what you mean by `3 ways to dereference stuff`? A hash reference `$href` may be dereferences as a hash by writing `%$href`. But much more often you will want to access one of its elements, and the element with key `key` of the hash referred to by `$href` is `$href->{key}`. The alternative `$$href{key}` is archaic and should be avoided

Comment: @jktstance: You would probably get more useful answers by asking for help with *specific* questions. Without them all we can do is to daub a general commentary over the entire situation. Being *"not much of a programmer "* you aren't really in a position to say that there is an *"awkward syntax to call them"* (and you don't mean **call* here—that is something else althogether). You won't gain friends by finding fault with a language that you don't know instead of acknowledging that the issue is really with your own lack of knoweldge

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that this:

```
$regression{$name}
```

represents a hashref, which looks like this:

```
{ file => '...something...'}
```

So, in order to dereference the hashref returned by `$regression{$name}`, you have to do something like:

```
%{ $regression{$name} }
```

In order to get the full hash.

In order to get the file property of the hash, do this:

```
$regression{$name}->{file}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: or, without having to specify a feature, in 5.24.0, postfix-deref (no need for the circumfix operator)! `$regression{$name}->%*`. I still am on the fence regarding this feature, but I thought I'd just throw it out there